# How to make basic area high Charts responsive?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, responsive, area-chart

Basic area chart in High Charts is responsive only when the page is not refreshed and as soon the page is refreshed it will not be responsive.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmK7I.jpg) the is the image of the page responsive with the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQHQL.jpg)this is the image of the same page when not responsive

I have tried this https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-ko0m91?file=/demo.jsx and still its not working

// the complete code is given below

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

export default function graph() {
const options = {
    title: {
        text: 'Emotion Analysis'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Honduras',
        data: [0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5]
    },
    {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Spain',
        data: [0.3, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1]
    },
    {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Afghanistan',
        data: [0.3, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1]
    },
    {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Sudan',
        data: [0.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]
    },
    {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Denmark',
        data: [0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]
    },
    {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Nepal',
        data: [0.1, 0.0, 0.9, 0.0, 0.4]
    },
    ],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

        };

     return (
            <Box>
                 <div style={{ height: "400px", marginTop: '15px' }}>
                 <HighchartsReact 
                           containerProps={{ style: { height: "100%" } }}
                       highcharts={Highcharts}
                       options={options} 
                       value= {options}
                       />
        </Box>
            );
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Archana Vishwanath, Could you add more information about how to reproduce the problem? The provided code seems to be incomplete and I couldn't investigate the issue in the below example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-rsyw1r?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: hi... I have added the complete code

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is still incomplete. Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor and provide me with a link to it.